# Merkle Tree Verification Consistently Fails in Solidity Smart Contract Tests

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, keccak, merkle-patricia-tries, merkleization

I am working on a Solidity smart contract for a lottery system using Merkle trees to verify winners. However, I consistently encounter an issue where the verify method of the Merkle Tree returns false during testing, indicating a mismatch between the provided proofs and the leaves.

Contract Overview:
The smart contract, involves users buying lottery tickets, participating in draws, and claiming rewards. The contract uses Merkle trees to manage and verify winners.

**Problem:**

During testing with Hardhat, the verify method of the Merkle Tree (using merkletreejs and keccak256 for hashing) always returns false. This occurs even when I am confident that the proofs, leaves, and roots should correctly align.

**Smart Contract Function for Claiming Rewards:**

```
function claimPreviousRoundRewards(
    uint256 _ticketId,
    uint256 _roundId,
    address _user,
    bytes32[] calldata _merkleProof
) public {
    // ... [initialization and setup code] ...

    bytes32 leaf = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_user));
    if (MerkleProof.verify(_merkleProof, trees.grandPriceWinners, leaf)) {
        // process claim
    }
    // ... [more verification for other prize types] ...
}
```

**Test Setup and Verification Logic:**

```
// Generating Merkle Tree and proofs
const leaves = winners.map(w => ethers.utils.keccak256(w.winner));
const tree = new MerkleTree(leaves, ethers.utils.keccak256, { sort: true });
const proof = tree.getProof(ethers.utils.keccak256(winner.winner));
const flattenedProof = proof.map(p => p[0]);

// Verifying in tests
const isVerified = tree.verify(proof, leaf, root);
```

**Attempts to Resolve:**

- Ensured consistent hashing (keccak256) in both contract and tests.
- Checked that leaf generation aligns with the contract's expectations.
- Verified the order and encoding of data for leaves.

**Questions**

- Why might the Merkle Tree verification consistently fail in this context?
- Are there specific considerations in Solidity or JavaScript that I might be overlooking related to Merkle tree implementation?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!